# find a conformal map which maps the exterior of two circles to upper half plane

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

> find a conformal map, which maps the exterior of circles $B(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$ and $B(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2})$, in addition excluded segment $[-2i,0]$, into the upper half plane.

My thoughts: I wish I can map each of these circles into a quadrant, map the segment into the eel axis and take completion, but I don't know how to do specifically. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't know the answer exactly, but we can proceed step by step together?

Comment: @MyGlasses yea I think so too, but i have difficulty construct every single step :(

Comment: What function maps unit circle to upper half plane.

Comment: @MyGlasses möbius transformation?

Comment: $w=i\dfrac{1-z}{1+z}$. mainly $w=\dfrac{1-z}{1+z}$ maps the unit circle to right half plane and $i$ rotates it $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ positively.

Comment: @MyGlasses I see, so should I get the weird shape in the problem to be unit circle first?

Comment: I think we should convert the unit circle to those two circles.

Comment: @MyGlasses why not converse? I need to map the unit circle to the plane in the last step...

Comment: But the question is about the exterior of two circle not unit circle! Can we proceed.

Comment: This needs to be better stated. Is the problem to find a conformal map of $\mathbb C \setminus (\{|z+1/2| \le 1/2\} \cup \{|z-1/2| \le 1/2\} \cup [-2i,0])$ into the open upper half plane?

Comment: @zhw. yes it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The function $f(z) = 1/(z-1/2)$ is a conformal map of $\mathbb C \setminus \{|z-1/2| \le 1/2\}$ into $D(0,2).$

Comment: I see this but how about the other circle and the line? seems $\{|z+1/2|\le 1/2\}$ has been mapped into a circle contained in $D(0,2)$, and I can't see what that segment maps to. Can you give a more detailed hint?

Comment: If $f$ does the above on that domain, it does it on any subdomain.